# UMVUE using complete and sufficient statistic

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, estimation

Let $X_1,X_2,...,X_n$ be a random sample from a normal distribution with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$.
I showed that $(\bar X,S^2)$ is jointly sufficient for estimating ($\mu$,$\sigma^2$) where $\bar X$ is the sample mean and $S^2$ is the sample variance.

Then assuming that$(\bar X,S^2)$ is also complete I have to show that $$\sqrt{ n-1\over 2}{\Gamma ({ n-1\over 2})\over\Gamma (\frac n2)} S$$
is a Uniformly Minimum Variance Unbiased Estimator for $\sigma$.

I think I have to use Lehman Scheffe theorem as $(\bar X,S^2)$ is jointly sufficient and complete for $\sigma$.
But how can I find a function which is unbiased for  $\sigma$ that contains both $(\bar X,S^2)$.

I don't understand how to work when there's  a **joint** sufficiency and completeness.

Comment: I'm closing this question because [it now has been answered on Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/106060/umvue-for-normal-distribution-sigma).

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2777526/321264, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1059938/321264, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/946013/321264