# What's the expectation of square root of Chi-square variable?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Setting
$$X_1,X_2,\ldots \overset{d}{\sim} \mathcal{N}(0,1)$$
$$V = X_1^2 + \ldots + X_n^2$$

Now I would like to find the expectation of $\sqrt{V}$. My biggest problem is I don't know how to write down the density of $\sqrt{V}$. Could someone help me derive it?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/946013/321264

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The distribution of $V$ is $\chi^2(n)$. The square root of a $\chi^2(n)$ random variable is a [$\chi(n)$ random variable](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChiDistribution.html).

Let the random variable $V$ have the chi-square distribution with $n$ degrees of freedom
with probability density function
$$
f_V(v) =
\begin{cases}
  \frac{v^{n/2-1} e^{-v/2}}{2^{n/2} \Gamma\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)},  & v \geq 0; \\ 0, & \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$
By the transformation technique, using the transformation $Y=g(V)=\sqrt{V}$, we have
$$
f_Y(y)=f_V(g^{-1}(y))\left|\frac{dv}{dy}\right|=\frac{(y^2)^{n/2-1} e^{-y^2/2}}{2^{n/2} \Gamma\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)}|2y|=\frac{y^{n-1} e^{-y^2/2}}{2^{n/2-1} \Gamma\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)}\qquad y>0
$$
which is the probability density function of the chi distribution with $n$ degrees of freedom.

The expectation is
$$
\Bbb{E}(Y)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}yf_Y(y)\textrm{d}y=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{y^{n} e^{-y^2/2}}{2^{n/2-1} \Gamma\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)}\textrm{d}y=\sqrt{2}\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)}
$$

Answer (score 5):

First note that each $X^{2}_i\sim Gamma(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2})$ for each $i$ (i.e. chi square with df=1) now to find distribution of $\sum_{i=1}^{n}X^2_{i}$ we see that using moment generating functions and fact that each are independent of each other that 
$$M_{\sum_{i=1}^{n}X^2_{i}}=M(t)^{n}=\left(\frac{\frac{1}{2}}{\frac{1}{2}-t}\right)^{\frac{n}{2}}$$
thus $\sum_{i=1}^{n}X^2_{i}\sim Gamma(\frac{n}{2},\frac{1}{2})$ thus $V=\sum_{i=1}^{n}X^2_{i}$ thus 
$$E(\sqrt{V})=\int_0^\infty \frac{\frac{1}{2}^{\frac{n}{2}}}{\Gamma(\frac{n}{2})}v^{\frac{1}{2}}v^{\frac{n}{2}-1}e^{-\frac{1}{2}x}dx=\frac{\frac{1}{2}^{\frac{n}{2}}}{\Gamma(\frac{n}{2})}\frac{\Gamma(\frac{n+1}{2})}{\frac{1}{2}^{\frac{n+1}{2}}}\int^\infty_0\frac{\frac{1}{2}^{\frac{n+1}{2}}}{\Gamma(\frac{n+1}{2})}v^{\frac{n+1}{2}-1}e^{-\frac{1}{2}x}dx=\frac{\sqrt{2}\Gamma(\frac{n+1}{2})}{\Gamma(\frac{n}{2})}$$

Comment: Care to explain why your end result is off by a factor of two from the above answer?

Comment: Nice catch, just simplified wrong second to last step it should be multiplied by $sqrt{2}$ at end