# Density function of $\sqrt{(\mathcal{N}_1(\mu,\sigma^2))^2+(\mathcal{N}_2(\mu,\sigma^2))^2}$ (Random walk)

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, normal-distribution, random-walk

I have 2D random walk and I would like to find out what distance I will travel after 200 steps. So I introduce two random variables $Z^{(200)}_x$ and $Z^{(200)}_y$ which tell me probabilities of my $x$ and $y$ position after 200 steps. Using [CLT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem) I can say that $$Z^{(200)}_x\approx \mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)\hspace{5pt}\text{and}\hspace{5pt}Z^{(200)}_y\approx \mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$$
for some parameters $\mu$ and $\sigma$ (they are the same in $x$ and $y$).  Since I am interested in the distance, I introduce new random variable $$Z^{(200)}=\sqrt{(Z^{(200)}_x)^2+(Z^{(200)}_y)^2}.$$
Using previous I can aproximate $Z^{(200)}$ and say that
$$Z^{(200)}\approx\sqrt{(\mathcal{N}_1(\mu,\sigma^2))^2+(\mathcal{N}_2(\mu,\sigma^2))^2}.$$

---

**Question**

How to compute density function of random variable $\sqrt{(\mathcal{N}_1(\mu,\sigma^2))^2+(\mathcal{N}_2(\mu,\sigma^2))^2}?$ I am interested in finding out an explicit formula.

This may be stated more broadly, i.e. "how to compute density function of the square root of random variable?"

Comment: See here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1059938/whats-the-expectation-of-square-root-of-chi-square-variable/1060019#1060019

Comment: You need Multi-Dimentional CLT. Let $Z_i$ be distribution of a single step. Then when properly scaled, $n^{-1/2}(S_n-E(Z))\to N(0,\Sigma)$. $P(\sqrt X\le t)=F_X(t^2)$. Differentiate to get density.

Comment: @A.S. To make approximation of $Z^{(200)}$ precise or to compute $\sqrt{(\mathcal{N}_1(\mu,\sigma^2))^2+(\mathcal{N}_2(\mu,\sigma^2))^2}?$

Comment: @ByronSchmuland "By the transformation technique, using the transformation $Y=g(Y)=\sqrt(Y)$, we have...". So there are general techniques to grasp such problems. I think I need to ivestigate them.