# Expected norm of linear maps

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics

I want to compute the expected norm of a vector-matrix multiplication. I have a vector $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ with norm one and a matrix $M \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, whose entries are taken from a gaussian distribution with mean zero and squared variance $2/n$. Which means, $M_{i,j} = \mathcal{N}(0,2/n)$.

I need to compute the expected value of the norm of the product, i.e. $ \mathbb{E}[||xM||].$

I have computed $\mathbb{E}[||xM||^2] = 2$, but i have no idea on how to get rid of that square sign.

EDIT: as suggested in the answer, I could use the chi or Gamma functions, but I'm somehow stuck:

I'd have $$\sqrt{\sum_i\sum_j^n x_i^2 M_{i,j}^2 + \sum_i \sum_j \sum_k x_i x_j M_{i,j} M_{i,k}}$$

I know I can use the gamma function for the first sum, and that the expected value of the second part goes to zero. The problem is that I can't compute the expected value of just the second part since it's under the square root. Any suggestions?

Thank you!

Comment: You might be able to use the [density of square root of chi squared](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1059938/whats-the-expectation-of-square-root-of-chi-square-variable/1060019) random variable since $\Vert xM\Vert$ is the sum of the square of gaussian random variables.

Comment: Thanks! but i'm not getting how i can adapt their case (variance 1) to mine. What would change in my case?