# How to prove that the variance of $2$-norm of a Gaussian random vector has a strictly positive lower bound?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $X$ be an $n$-dimensional Gaussian random vector. Namely its $n$-components are i.i.d standard normal random variables. Consider its $2$-norm $\|X\|_2$. It is intuitively very clear to me that there exists a positive absolute constant $c$ (independent of $n$) such that

$$\text{Var}(\|X\|_2) \ge c$$

But how do we give this a rigorous proof? I don't really need to know what $c$ is, as long as it is an absolute constant.

---

Just in case someone would expect $\text{Var}(\|X\|_2) \ge \text{Var}(|X_1|)$ to hold, but $\text{Var}$ doesn't have such monotonicity condition.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is related to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1059938/whats-the-expectation-of-square-root-of-chi-square-variable) post. I do not give a rigorous proof here, however note that,
\begin{align}
\text{Var}(\|X\|_2) = \text{Var}\left(\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i^2}\right).
\end{align}
The square root of the sum, i.e, $\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i^2}$ follows a [$\chi(n)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi_distribution) distribution. The variance is given by,

\begin{align}
 \text{Var}\left(\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i^2}\right) &= n - \mu^2, \\
\mu &= \sqrt{2}\frac{\Gamma((n+1)/2)}{\Gamma(n/2)}.
\end{align}

Here $\Gamma(\cdot)$ is the [gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function). Depending on your taste for rigorous, [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/6104/proving-that-the-squares-of-normal-rvs-is-chi-square-distributed) is a proof that the sum of squared standard normal variables follows a chi-square distribution with $n$ degrees of freedom and [here](http://www.math.wm.edu/%7Eleemis/chart/UDR/PDFs/ChisquareChi.pdf) is a proof that the square root of a chi-squared distribution, follows a chi distribution. I hope this is indeed what you are looking for.